# NotFoundHttpException in Laravel middleware and controller

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel and learning basics from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_middleware.htm

After installation I have created RoleMiddleware and TestController.

**RoleMiddleware.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class RoleMiddleware
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    echo "Role: ".$role;
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

and **TestController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{
//
public function index(){
  echo "<br>Test Controller.";
}
}
```

and app\http\ **routes.php**

```
 Route::get('/role',[
'middleware' => 'Role:editor',
'uses' => 'TestController@index',
 ]);
```

and in **Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
  'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware   \AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
  'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
  'Age' => \App\Http\Middleware\AgeMiddleware::class,
  'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
  'Role' => \App\Http\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
  'terminate' => \App\Http\Middleware\TerminateMiddleware::class,
  ];
```

After written all these code I have executed this using http://localhost:8000/role but it gives NotFoundHttpException, Please help me to solve this issue..

Comment: which version laravel you are using ? in latest version routes file is inside `routes/web.php`

Comment: Learn basics from laracasts instead, and use latest version of Laravel not some ancient one ;)

Comment: I am using 5.4.36 version

Comment: Laravel 5.4 doesn't have **app\http\routes.php** file. You must be using 5.2.x or lesser version!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using some older version of Laravel, as your routes are listed in app\http\routes.php file  because in newer versions, it is actually **routes\web.php** file:

Then you made a mistake in your route:

```
 Route::get('/role', ['middleware' => 'Role:editor', 'uses' => ]);
```

http routes must have a callback/closure, whether it is custom function or using a controller... Try with following basic options:

```
Route::get('/role', function() { return "Working"; });
```

Also check whether your route is not listed as excepted route

If its working, then play with middlewares!!!

Answer (score 0):

i cant send a comment to ask for hole error ( bcs of my reputation )
but i write middle ware in this way . maybe its help you :

first make sure that $role is string or put it in json_encode ( on  RoleMiddleware.php )
==> echo "Role: ".json_encode($role);

then change your rout to below :
Route::get('/role', 'TestController@index')->middleware('Role');

send back to me the result

Comment: I have changed according to this code, but got same result, NotFoundHttpException

Comment: could you send the error. could you run any controller without middleware. ( for example remove this middleware and run controller )